# Travis CI : Nightwatch js: Error while trying to create ChromeDriver process: spawn EACCES. Running perfectly locally

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, nightwatch.js

Error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxN1B.png)

Code:

```
"webdriver" : {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "./drivers/chromedriver.exe",
    "port": 9515,
  },
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What is your question exactly and what did you try? Thanks.

Comment: I have some test scripts(written in nightwatch js) which are running perfectly in my local system. But when i configured it on travis CI , scripts started failing with error as "Error while trying to create ChromeDriver process: spawn EACCES."

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it looks like you're trying to run the Windows chromedriver on a Linux Travis CI instance.

You probably want to have [two different sets of test settings](https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/#environment-specific-settings), one for Windows and one for Linux. Or else [configure Travis CI to use Windows](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/windows#using-windows).

I'm not sure what version of Chrome (or Chromium?) is installed by default in Travis CI instances; to get the latest stable version, add this to your `.travis.yml`:

```
addons:
  chrome: stable
```

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/chrome

Then, for the nightwatch config, it should be

```
"server_path": "node_modules/.bin/chromedriver",
```

That was [enough to get me working today](https://github.com/matthewmueller/next-cookies/tree/40f036e3f8fc6365d787daa9521d019ede7f298e) but I'm afraid that there might be one more issue that I haven't figured out yet: travis CI doesn't let you specify a specific version of Chrome to install, but chromedriver versions are matched to Chrome versions. I put my chromedriver version as `*` to always install the latest, but I have a feeling that my current config is going to fail eventually, so if anyone else figures that out, please leave a comment here.